# Why this SPRITE image is not properly positioned when using Chrome (ok with others)?

Tags: css, image, google-chrome

I have a button with an image coming from a [strip image](https://i.ibb.co/58qB7Fd/filetypes32.png) and a label next to the image.
However, on chrome and only on chrome, the most I'm using an image from the end of the strip the most it gets bad positioned vertically.
Do you have any idea why and how to fix it ?

Compare [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndsq3acg/1/) when opening in Chrome:
[image]

Or in FF or Edge :

[image]

The css used is below:

```
.file-type-pdf
{
    background-position: 0px -615px;
}
```

Many thanks !

Comment: I think your browser Chrome is zoomed in (not at 100% view). Use `Ctrl` + `0` (or on Mac `Cmd` + `0`)

Comment: You should not just show a minimal, incomplete CSS snippet, and then just refer to a fiddle - all information relevant to your problem, is supposed to be contained in your question itself - see [mre].

Comment: That being said - why `background-size: cover`? In combination with a sprite image, I don’t see what sense that is supposed to make? Once I remove _that_, I get the same result in Chrome and Firefox (not the _right_ result, but the same - so you will still have to correct your background-position for some of those icons.)

Comment: @Roy: I'm in 100% but you're right the zoom affect it : at 80% is see it properly.

Comment: @CBroe: Ok noted, but I wanted to avoid to duplicate code from jsfiddle.

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for your help, you're right the problem is with the `background-size: cover`. It's purpose was to resize the image source (32px) with property size as 26px. The `background-size:26px 26px` works only for single image and not sprite image. Proably the best solution is to change the image source or avoid sprite image. What do you think?

Comment: If you just need to modify the image width, then use `background-size:26px auto` (or just `background-size:26px`, with just one value, that one refers to the width, and height is set to auto implicitly.) https://jsfiddle.net/1sqha7o5/ - looks okay to me in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Oh wow THANKS I didn't think about that option (don't specify the height value of the background-size). Thanks a lot !